# ShareActionProvider menu style

Tags: android, styles, shareactionprovider

I have this menu when the user clicks on the ShareActionProvider:
[image]

How can I change its background color. I suppose I have to style it but I cannot find anywhere how.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the source code, if there is no documentation on how to apply a style. I haven't actually tried to style the ShareActionProvider, but I got quite some clues from the code:

1. [ShareActionProvider.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.java) is probably responsible in the first place
2. [ActivityChooserView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/ActivityChooserView.java) looks like the used view class which leads to ...
3. [abc_activity_chooser_view.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_activity_chooser_view.xml) is most likely the used view, which has `?attr/activityChooserViewStyle` applied as the style reference
4. looking into [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml) yields in line 75:

   ```
   <item name="activityChooserViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActivityChooserView</item>
   ```

Would love to hear if this works, as I might be in the same situation soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did to style it was edit our styles.xml.

```
<!-- ACTION BAR -->
<style name="ToolbarTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
    <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/ToolbarPopupListStyle</item>
    <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/ToolbarPopupListStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="ToolbarStyle">
    <item name="android:background">?colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextAppearance">@style/collapsedToolbarText</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/collapsedToolbarText</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarPopupListStyle">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#00ff00</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenuTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

Of course, these styles have to be referenced in the layout file where Toolbar is referenced:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    style="@style/ToolbarStyle"/>
```

I have the weird feeling, though, that styles should have a parent style. But it works out like this.

Thanks to @Brian who pointed me in the right direction.